# How can we take key and value both from user and assign it together

Tags: lua

**
Actually I'm working on a program in which Use enter a string which contains name and number such as Denial 40 I have to story it in a table where Denial is key and 40 as value so, I can do further process with table..
**

```
local class = {}
  for i=1,N or 0    --N enter by user no. of classmember
    local name=io.read() --takes the key
    local credit = io.read("*n","*l")--takes the credit as value
    
    class[name] = credit --assign the credit to the key

  end
```

Comment: Good. And what have you attempted so far?

Comment: I edited but while toggle with key and value I have to press enter but I'm finding way where key and value taken in one string separated by space and assign as corresponding..

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this:

```lua
local credits = {}

while true do
    io.write 'Type name and credit or just press Enter to finish: '
    local name, credit  = io.read():match '^([^%d%s]+)%s*(%d+)$'
    if name then
        credits [name] = tonumber (credit)
    else
        break
    end
end

-- Show credits:
for name, credit in pairs (credits) do
    print (name .. "'s credit is " .. tostring (credit))
end
```

- User will be prompted to enter strings containing name an number in an endless loop. It will only terminate when the user enters an empty or unparseable string.

  - the condition that finishes the loop is not in its header (after `while` or `until`) because it's rather complicated, involving printing an invitation and returning two variables, which are needed in the loop body. In simpler cases, that would not be the best choice (also, assignments in Lua are not expressions and do not return a value, unlike C or PHP),
  - **but see the update below!**
- User's input is immediately parsed into two *captures* with a regular expression.

  - `[^%d%s]` means neither digit, nor space (we don't want trailing spaces in names); `%s`, whitespace; `%d`, digit; and `+`, one or more.
- `name` (and `credit`) will be `nil`, as soon as the user types something else than `Alice 10` or suchlike; and `break` will end the loop,
- and if `name` is not `nil` and therefore not *falsy*, the value `credit` will be recorded in `credits` under the key `name`.

**UPD**: This is a more elegant but somewhat esoteric solution, based on [*generic for*](https://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.5.html):

```lua
local credits = {}

local function get_credit ()
    io.write 'Type name and credit or just press Enter to finish: '
    return io.read():match '^([^%d%s]+)%s*(%d+)$'
end

for name, credit in get_credit do -- note the absence of ().
    credits [name] = tonumber (credit)
end
    
-- Show credits:
for name, credit in pairs (credits) do
    print (name .. "'s credit is " .. tostring (credit))
end
```